# Strange jquery.min.js link in <head> causing ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: jquery, wordpress, debugging, head

I've searched and searched for a solution to this problem, but nothing so far.

Either Wordpress Core or a plugin is writing this in our  tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.ourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.ourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.ourdomain.comhttps//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var ajax_request = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/www.ourdomain.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Obviously the 3rd line here is causing an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error and making some mobile devices hang.

We have a number of plugins running but becuase the website is live, there are some critical plugins which we CANNOT deactivate for testing.

We've searched the DB but no entries there. Also searched all wp-content files, but nothing there either.

1. This is a long shot, but any ideas where this could be coming from? :)
2. Perhaps suggestions on how to debug a problem like this WITHOUT deactivating all plugins?
3. Or perhaps a tip on how to redirect this to the correct link using .htaccess?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

WP Campaign Monitor plugin problem. jQuery conflict resolved in latest update :)